# Spring Data Redis | Unable to evict entire cache using @Cacheable or CacheManager?

Tags: spring, redis, spring-data-redis

I've been using Spring Data Redis and embedded Redis for testing.

```
spring-boot-starter-parent 2.7.12

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>it.ozimov</groupId>
  <artifactId>embedded-redis</artifactId>
  <version>0.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```

However, I've tried evicting using two approaches like below:

```
# Removing all entries in a cache doesn't work
@CacheEvict(value = "Foo", allEntries = true)
public void evictCache(){}

public void evictCacheUsingCacheManager() {
  cacheManager.getCacheNames()
    .stream()
    .map(cacheManager::getCache)
    .forEach(Cache::clear);
}
```

The cache entry still remains in the cache, but it seems as though cache eviction operation only works by evicting by `key`, like so:

```
# Removing a single entry works
@CacheEvict(value = "Foo", key = "#p0")
public void evictCache(String key){}
```

Since all the entries with key should belong in the same `Foo` cache. Why is clearing the cache not working as intended?